# Unable to extract highest sales after grouping them

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me figure out the error and how to correct it?

```
select *, max(sales) 
from
(
select product, '1-4' as weeks, sum(sales) as sales from Table5 t
where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (1,2,3,4)
group by product
union
select product, '2-5' as weeks, sum(sales)as sales  from Table5 t
where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (2,3,4,5)
group by product
union
select product, '3-6' as weeks, sum(sales)as sales from Table5 t
where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (3,4,5,6)
group by product
union
select product, '4-7' as weeks, sum(sales) as sales from Table5 t
where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (4,5,6,7)
group by product
union
select product, '5-8' as weeks, sum(sales)as sales from Table5 t
where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (5,6,7,8)
group by product
 )a
 group by product
order by product, sales desc
```

Error
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 182
Column 'a.weeks' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I want to group the sales find the product sold highest in which weeks like this.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: When you do a group by, you need to do some sort of aggregation on every column you are selecting. so for this example, you will change the first line to ```Select product, max(sales) ...```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, if you just want one of the `UNION` result terms in the result (the highest summed sales value (per week)...

Perhaps you want this (notice the `PARTITION BY weeks ...` clause).
This finds the product with the highest sales per week.  If you want the highest sales week per product, change the `PARTITION BY` to ... `PARTITION BY product`.

I changed the SQL below to produce results per product:

```
WITH xrows AS (
      select a.*
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY sales DESC) AS n
        from (
              select product, '1-4' as weeks, sum(sales) as sales from Table5 t
               where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (1,2,3,4)
               group by product
               union
              select product, '2-5' as weeks, sum(sales) as sales  from Table5 t
               where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (2,3,4,5)
               group by product
               union
              select product, '3-6' as weeks, sum(sales) as sales from Table5 t
               where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (3,4,5,6)
               group by product
               union
              select product, '4-7' as weeks, sum(sales) as sales from Table5 t
               where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (4,5,6,7)
               group by product
               union
              select product, '5-8' as weeks, sum(sales) as sales from Table5 t
               where t.WEEKNUMBER IN (5,6,7,8)
               group by product
             ) a
     )
SELECT *
  FROM xrows
 WHERE n = 1
 ORDER BY product
;
```

Here's the (updated - see the last panel) working test case, without data.  Feel free to add data, if you wish and post the updated URL:
[Working test case for both cases, per week and per product](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8b6bb19daa1193e5222379aecce7eb0)

The bottom line is this is a functional dependence issue with respect to `GROUP BY`.  Window functions is just one way to avoid that functional dependence issue.  There are others.

Result with data added:

[image: Test case result]

Here's one with an arguments CTE term to drive the generation of data, to easily change the parameters: number of periods, start week, size of the period (in weeks), etc:

```
WITH args (numweeks, numperiods, startweek) AS (
        SELECT 4, 5, 1
     )
   , periods (week1, week2, nw) AS (
        SELECT startweek, startweek+numweeks-1, numperiods FROM args UNION ALL
        SELECT week1+1, week2+1, nw - 1 FROM periods
         WHERE nw > 1
     )
   , calcweeks AS (
        SELECT product, week1, week2, SUM(sales) AS sales
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY SUM(sales) DESC) AS n
          FROM table5  AS t
          JOIN periods AS p
            ON t.weeknumber BETWEEN p.week1 AND p.week2
         GROUP BY product, week1, week2
     )
SELECT *
  FROM calcweeks
 WHERE n = 1
 ORDER BY product
;

/*
+---------+-------+-------+-------+---+
| product | week1 | week2 | sales | n |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+---+
| a       |     3 |     6 |   184 | 1 |
| b       |     1 |     4 |   103 | 1 |
| c       |     3 |     6 |    77 | 1 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+---+
*/
```

[Added solution to the end of the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0198bf83bce2c5e049bd1c77529f714b)

There are some ties in the test case data, that's all.  The above was correct:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+---+
| product | week1 | week2 | sales | n |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+---+
| a       |     3 |     6 |   184 | 1 |
| a       |     2 |     5 |   184 | 2 |
| a       |     1 |     4 |   183 | 3 |
| a       |     4 |     7 |   121 | 4 |
| a       |     5 |     8 |    59 | 5 |
| b       |     1 |     4 |   103 | 1 |
| b       |     2 |     5 |    96 | 2 |
| b       |     3 |     6 |    96 | 3 |
| b       |     4 |     7 |    96 | 4 |
| b       |     5 |     8 |    52 | 5 |
| c       |     4 |     7 |    77 | 1 |
| c       |     5 |     8 |    77 | 2 |
| c       |     2 |     5 |    77 | 3 |
| c       |     3 |     6 |    77 | 4 |
| c       |     1 |     4 |    21 | 5 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+---+
```

Comment: Added data to the test case in dbfiddle.uk.  See the last panel for the result you requested, I believe.  It's the SQL shown above.

Comment: The issue of breaking ties, or how to handle multiple periods with the same SUM for the same product should be addressed in the requirement.

Comment: RANK or DENSE_RANK could be used to show all periods which match the criteria per product, instead of just picking the row that happens to be at n = 1 for each product.

Answer (score 2):

For each product, you want the weeks where it was the highest.  I would suggest the following approach:

- Aggregate by product week.
- Do a rolling sum of 4 weeks.
- Choose the highest value.

Assuming that you have data for every week, then you can phrase this as:

```
select product, week - 3 as start_week, week as end_wek, sales_4
from (select product, week, sum_sales, sales_4,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by sales_4 desc) as seqnum
      from (select product, week, sum(sales) as sum_sales,
                   sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by product 
                                         order by week
                                         rows between 3 preceding and current row
                                        ) as sales_4
            from table5 t
            group by product, week
           ) t
     where week >= 4 and week <= 8
    ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this does not use `union` so it is much more easily generalized to more weeks.

EDIT:

If you don't have data for all weeks, you can use `apply`:

```
with s as (
      select product, weeknumber, sum(sales) as sum_sales
      from table5 t
      group by product, weeknumber
     )
select product, weeknumber - 3 as start_week, weeknumber as end_week, sales_4
from (select s.*, s2.sales_4,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by sales_4 desc) as seqnum
      from s outer apply
           (select sum(s2.sum_sales) as sales_4
            from s s2
            where s2.product = s.product and
                  s2.weeknumber <= s.weeknumber and
                  s2.weeknumber >= s.weeknumber - 3
           ) s2
       ) s
where seqnum = 1 and s.weeknumber between 4 and 8;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa616c3060a3d123441f1c02f95fa16c) is your db<>fiddle with this version.

Comment: Agreed. I like the approach.  I'm just not sure it's correct, as is.  I've added your SQL to the last panels of the following fiddle for review (with a tiny typo corrected).  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c7b511bec33d77f9f851358b9856708   ... The UNION wasn't necessary.  I left it in my cases more for the original poster, who probably understands that form.

Comment: @JonArmstrong . . . I added another version to handle missing weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    product,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKNUMBER IN (1,2,3,4) THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS [1-4],
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKNUMBER IN (2,3,4,5) THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS [2-5],
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKNUMBER IN (3,4,5,6) THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS [3-6],
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKNUMBER IN (4,5,6,7) THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS [4-7],
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKNUMBER IN (5,6,7,8) THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS [5-8]
FROM Table5
GROUP BY
    product;
```

Comment: Hello Tim, this will give me data by the columns, but I need it in weeks column like in the after image I attached.